# How large should my frequency array be if i want to compress an image using huffman code?

Tags: java, huffman-code

So I've been implementing huffman code to compress text files, and this is how i've been counting the repetitions of each character

```
    BufferedInputStream fin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    byte[] b = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    int[] counter = new int[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        char ch = (char) b[i];
        counter[ch]++;
    }
```

I want to expand my huffman code to also compress other types of files, but i'm not really sure how to do that? do i make an array that holds up to all possible uncode characters like this

```
     int[] counter=new int[65536];
```

I don't think making an array that large is very sufficient but i'm not really sure how else to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Process the characters as a sequence of bytes encoded as UTF-8. Then just keep your byte frequency coding.